# Microsoft Edge - Dark Mode

Tags: microsoft-edge, dark-mode

I know there is now this setting in Microsoft Edge:

```
edge://flags/#enable-force-dark
```

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/143927-enable-disable-dark-mode-websites-microsoft-edge-chromium.html

You can enable dark mode which works well for many sites. But is there a way to do this on demands for certain sites? For example, there are certain websites I would like to use this dark mode with. But for others, to use the normal mode as the dark mode does not render well.

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to use the "Dark mode" chrome extension

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-mode/dmghijelimhndkbmpgbldicpogfkceaj

Comment: So this means that there is not facility using the built-in dark mode extension that is part of the latest MSEdge then? Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, yes. the built in dark mode doesn't allow filtering like the extension does.